# How can I determine all ajax requests are resolved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Here is my code:

```
function ajaxRequest(value, path, website){
    var status = false;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        window[website] = $.ajax({
            url :  path,
            type : 'GET',
            data: { "name": value,
                    "_token": $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },

            beforeSend: function(){
                if(window[website] != null) {
                    window[website].abort();
                }
            },
            success: function (people) {
                status = true;
                resolve([status, people]);
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                reject([status, textStatus]);

            },

            timeout: 20000

        });
    });
}
```

And I call the function like this:

```
ajaxRequest('Jack', 'search/twitter', 'twitter').then(function(res) { console.log(res)}, function(err){console.log(err)});
ajaxRequest('Jack', 'search/instagram', 'instagram').then(function(res) { console.log(res)}, function(err){console.log(err)});
```

Now I need to know those two ajax requests are done. How can I do that?

Noted that I think I have to use `promise.all()`, but not sure how can I use it in my case.

Comment: You can pass function calls to `$.when()`

Comment: @guest271314 emm, not sure how you mean exactly, do you have any example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `promise.all()` is invented to solve exactly that problem.
All it does is to return a **new** Promise that will resolved when **all** the given Promises are resolved.

In your case, you can wrap your 2 ajax calls with `Promise.all` something like that:

```
promise.all([
   ajaxRequest('Jack', 'search/twitter', 'twitter').then(function(res) { console.log(res)}, function(err){console.log(err)}),
   ajaxRequest('Jack', 'search/instagram', 'instagram').then(function(res) { console.log(res)}, function(err){console.log(err)})
]).then(([response1, response2]) => {
   // Here you execute your logic when both of the promises are resolved.
})
```

Comment: In your code, I'm actually calling that functions twice. One time normally *(in my code)*, and one time into `promise.all()` *(in your code)*

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to wrap your 2 calls with the `Promise.all` like in my code.

Comment: Well no, I need to get the result of those ajax requests separately, not when all are done.

Comment: Ok, so, you can put your code (with the `then`) inside the `Promise.all`, then the `then` of `Promise.all` will be called when both of the ajax's are resolved

Comment: Also, I don't need to `[response1, response2]`, can I remove it?

Comment: When you put then `.then(function(res) {console.log(res)})` on the end of the ajax calls with no return value, you LOSE the return value from the ajax calls so `Promise.all()` does not get any return values.  Your `.then()` handlers need to return the values if they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass function calls to `$.when()`. Note, `jQuery.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object, using `Promise` constructor is not necessary

```
$.when(ajaxRequest(), ajaxRequest())
.then(function(...results) {
  // do stuff with `results` array
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error(errorThrown)
})
```

Comment: Well no, I need to get the result of those ajax requests separately *(asynchronous)*, not at the same time when all are done. And I just need to know all of them are done to stop blinker magnifier.

Comment: See [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Chained `.then()` should not be called until each asynchronous or synchronous call returns a value. `.fail()` is reached if any `$.ajax()` call is rejected or an error is thrown.

Comment: If you want to make each asynchronous separately what is the issue with code at Question?

Comment: The problem is I don't know when all requests are done. *(to stop progress icon (in other word, to disable "is working" mode) )*

Comment: Using either `Promise.all()` or `$.when()` should provide expected result.

Comment: I know *(as I've mentioned in my question)*, but I don't know how should I use it in my code structure. For example, I'm trying to implement @Felix Mosheev's solution, but nothing happens!

Comment: What is purpose of `.abort()` call? Only a single `.then()` is necessary to perform action with response of both requests.

Comment: That `.abort()` call with cancel an ajax request which is sent already *(still working)* and the same request will be send again right away.

Comment: Are you expecting a value at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()` or `$.when()`? What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Not sure why `.abort()` call is necessary? Does `jQuery.ajax()` have an `.abort()` method?

Comment: No, I don't need any value at `.then()`, I just need to execute this line `clearInterval(isBlinking)` there. But it seems that line doesn't execute.

Comment: It is not related to ajax. You know, I set a interval before everything in a global scope *(when searching starts)*, Now I need to clear that interval when everything is done https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu6e1.png

Comment: Again, either `Promise.all()` or `$.when()` should provide expected result. Note, `clearInterval` does not appear at text of original Question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok thank you .. just can you please add the `Promise` version of this solution in your answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "the `Promise` version"?

Comment: Currently your answer is by using `$.when()`. Now I want to see the same solution by using `Promise.all()`

Comment: @FelixMosheev posted a solution using `Promise.all()`

Comment: Ah, so you believe its correct, right? Just can I remove `[response1, response2]` in the `.then()`? because no need to them. Can I chain `.catch()` block? How can I get the error message in it?

Comment: Belief is irrelevant. Try the code to determine the result yourself. Yes, if you only need to perform a specific task at `.then()` that does not use response from server.

Comment: As my last question, do you know how can I get the error message in the `.catch` bock? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e20c1abfa6d3b597999c3a66044080d#file-gistfile1-txt-L28

Comment: @MartinAJ `.catch(err => {console.error(err);
    stopBlinking();})`